# Using Linq, how would one join two tables without a foreign key relationship between the two tables?

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

So let's say we have these two tables:

```
    CARS
    ID   CAR_MODEL 
    11   Mustang          
    22   Camaro           
    33   F-150     

    PARTS
    ID   CAR_ID  PART_NAME       
    1    11      Steering Wheel  
    2    22      Steering Wheel 
    3    22      Headlights
```

**NOTE: there is no foreign key relationship in the database between the `PARTS.CAR_ID` and `CARS.ID` columns.**

---

Without the foreign key, what sort of linq query would be used to obtain these results:

```
    CARS
    ID   CAR_MODEL        PART_NAME_LIST
    11   Mustang          Steering Wheel
    22   Camaro           Steering Wheel, Headlights
    33   F-150            (null)
```

---

Environment: SQL Server 2014, linq-to-sql

---

edit: here is what I have so far, but this results in 4 rows in the results (2 for Camaro), instead of 3, and it does not include any parts.

```
from C in db.CARS
join P in db.PARTS on C.ID equals P.CAR_ID
select new{
   ID = C.ID,
   CAR_MODEL = C.CAR_MODEL,
   PART_NAME_LIST = ???
}
```

Comment: Your LINQ syntax isn't compilable. Can you put in actual valid LINQ code?

Comment: Thanks and it has been updated.

Comment: I think you want to use a group join, which is represented in fluent syntax by `into`, like a left join implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a fluent syntax group join:

```
var sub = (from C in db.CARS
          join P in db.PARTS on C.ID equals P.CAR_ID into Pj
          select new {
              C.ID,
              C.CAR_MODEL,
              PART_NAMES = from p in Pj select p.PART_NAME
          })
          .AsEnumerable();
var ans = from icp in sub
          select new {
              icp.ID,
              icp.CAR_MODEL,
              PART_NAME_LIST = String.Join(", ", icp.PART_NAMES)
```

I would probably switch to lambda syntax in the `select` in my code:

```
var ans = (from C in db.CARS
           join P in db.PARTS on C.ID equals P.CAR_ID into Pj
           select new {
               C.ID,
               C.CAR_MODEL,
               PART_NAMES = Pj.Select(cpj => cpj.PART_NAME)
          })
          .AsEnumerable()
          .Select(icp => new {
              icp.ID,
              icp.CAR_MODEL,
              PART_NAME_LIST = String.Join(", ", icp.PART_NAMES)
          });
```

Comment: When I run this, I get this error message: "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String Join(System.String, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.String])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."

Comment: Unfortunately Entity Framework can't translate everything LINQ to SQL can. Since you are using EF, you can simulate what LINQ to SQL is doing instead, though it could have performance consequences depending on what you do with `ans`. I'll update the code.

Answer (score 1):

For concatenating strings you have to use `string.Join`. The easiest way to do that is in a subquery:

```
(
from c in db.CARS
select new
{
   ID = c.ID,
   CAR_MODEL = c.CAR_MODEL,
   PART_NAME_LIST = db.PARTS
                      .Where(p => c.ID equals p.CAR_ID)
                      .Select(p => p.PART_NAME)
}
).AsEnumerable()
.Select(c => new
{
    ID = c.ID,
    CAR_MODEL = c.CAR_MODEL,
    PART_NAME_LIST = string.Join(", ", cPART_NAME_LIST) 
})
```

Entity Framework doesn't support `string.Join`, so you have to split the query in a part that EF can translate into SQL and a part that's executed in memory, separated by `AsEnumerable()`.

Comment: Sorry, aren't these the same thing? I'm using linq to hit a SQL Server database so I assume this means I'm using linq-to-sql.